# Qt - QLocalSocket Signal-Slot not working resulting in deadlocks in destructor

Tags: c++, qt, networking, signals-slots

I am using QLocalSocket and QLocalServer for inter process communication on Windows 7 using VS 2010 and Qt 5.5.1.

After sending over 256 messages to the other process the destructor in CIPSocket freezes. I traced the problem to a signal-slot problem in qtbase\src\corelib\ioqwinoverlappedionotifier.cpp where the emitted signal _q_notify() in notify(DWORD numberOfBytes, DWORD errorCode, OVERLAPPED *overlapped) does not result in a call of _q_notified(). Therefore the Semaphore hSemaphore exceeds its max-count, resulting in the deadlock in the destructor.

What could be the reason for the signal-slot not working? I could not find any disconnects or block signals.

Thanks in advance.

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QThread>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Server (0) or Socket (1)?\n");
    char c = getchar();
    if (c == '0') {
        QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
        CIPServer server;
        app.exec();
    }
    else if (c == '1') {
        CIPSocket socket;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= 256; ++i) {
            socket.update(i);
            QThread::msleep(10);
        }
    }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   CIPSocket
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CIPSocket::CIPSocket()
: m_bIsReady(false)
{
    m_pSocket = new QLocalSocket(this);
    m_stream.setDevice(m_pSocket);

    connect(m_pSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connectionReady()));
    connect(m_pSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(connectionLost()));

    m_pSocket->connectToServer("DemoServer");
}

CIPSocket::~CIPSocket()
{
    delete m_pSocket;
    m_pSocket = NULL;
}

void CIPSocket::update(int i)
{
    if (m_bIsReady)
        m_stream << i;
}

void CIPSocket::connectionReady()
{ m_bIsReady = true; }

void CIPSocket::connectionLost()
{ m_bIsReady = false; }

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   CIPServer
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CIPServer::CIPServer(QObject* parent)
: QLocalServer(parent)
{
    if (!listen("DemoServer")) {
        throw ("Could not connect to 'DemoServer'");
    }
    connect(this, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(socketConnected()));
}

CIPServer::~CIPServer()
{}

void CIPServer::socketConnected()
{
    qDebug() << "Connected";
    m_pConnection = nextPendingConnection();
    m_stream.setDevice(m_pConnection);
    connect(m_pConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()), m_pConnection, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(m_pConnection, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(update()));
}

void CIPServer::update()
{
    if (m_pConnection->bytesAvailable() >= 4) {
        int i;
        m_stream >> i;
        qDebug() << i;
    }
}
```

main.h:

```
#include <QtNetwork/QLocalServer>
#include <QtNetwork/QLocalSocket>
#include <QtCore/QDataStream>
#include <QtCore/QThread>


    /// \brief Creates a socket for inter-process communication
    class CIPSocket
        : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT;

    public:
        /// Constructor
        CIPSocket();
        /// Destructor
        virtual ~CIPSocket();

        /// Send the data
        void update(int i);

    public slots:
        /// Enables updating
        void connectionReady();
        /// Disables updating
        void connectionLost();

    private:
        /// The target stream
        QDataStream m_stream;
        /// The socket connecting to server
        QLocalSocket* m_pSocket;
        /// Indicates if the socket is connected
        bool m_bIsReady;
    };

    /// \brief Creates a server for inter-process communication
    class CIPServer
        : public QLocalServer
    {
        Q_OBJECT;

    public:
        /// Constructor
        CIPServer(QObject* parent = NULL);
        /// Destructor
        virtual ~CIPServer();
        /// Starts the server
        void start();

    private slots:
        /// Connects the socket to the stream and to the update function
        void socketConnected();
        /// Reads the data from the stream and emits a the results
        void update();

    private:
        /// The currently connected socket
        QLocalSocket* m_pConnection;
        /// The incoming stream
        QDataStream m_stream;
    };
```

demo.pro:

```
CONFIG += qt debug
QT += network
HEADERS += main.h
SOURCES += main.cpp
CONFIG += console
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example, but it does not compile, because of unknown CSocketThread.

Comment: Sorry, there was some extra code i forgot to remove. It should be compileable now.

Comment: Some ideas: Try `bool QLocalSocket::flush()` .. maybe you get some data stuck in the internal buffer. Also, maybe adapt your code to use `bool QLocalSocket::waitForBytesWritten(int msecs = 30000)`

Comment: @Derick Schoonbee: I tried this, but without success. The data is transmitted correctly. The problem, as described, is with the Semaphore in qtbase\src\corelib\ioqwinoverlappedionotifier.cpp overflowing, due to the artifacts of the asynchronous communication not being deleted, because the connected slot to do this is not being called. The question is why the connected slot is not being called.

Comment: Try to remove the line in the destructor `delete m_pSocket;` The QLocalSocket will be deleted when the parent is deleted.

Comment: Ran your code on my Mac and it seems fine. Maybe it's Windows specific?

Comment: I tried on Windows 10 with Qt 5.5.1 and gcc version 4.9.2: Some of your diagnosis may be true: if you try with less than 256 transmissions, e.g. 100, then the client ends normally. But when the client hangs, then it hangs not in destructor, but deep in Qt. I can transfer the problem to Qt support.

Comment: @Roland: Already reported it to Qt: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54567. I thought that maybe I forgot some preparation with the socket, but it seems the bug is with Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs due to the event loop not running. Starting QCoreApplication starts the event loop, but waits for the application to quit. Therefore the sending has to be done in another thread.
Attached code shows the correct usage.

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    printf("Server (0) or Socket (1)?\n");
    char c = getchar();
    if (c == '0') {
        CIPServer server;
        QCoreApplication::exec();
    }
    else if (c == '1') {
        CIPSocket socket;
        CSender sender(500);
        QObject::connect(&sender, SIGNAL(sendMessage(int)), &socket, SLOT(update(int)));
        QObject::connect(&sender, SIGNAL(allMessagesSent()), &socket, SLOT(close()));
        sender.start();
        QCoreApplication::exec();
    }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   CIPSocket
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CIPSocket::CIPSocket()
: m_bIsReady(false)
{
    m_pSocket = new QLocalSocket(this);
    m_stream.setDevice(m_pSocket);

    connect(m_pSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connectionReady()));
    connect(m_pSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(connectionLost()));

    m_pSocket->connectToServer("DemoServer");
}

CIPSocket::~CIPSocket()
{
    delete m_pSocket;
    m_pSocket = NULL;
}

void CIPSocket::update(int i)
{
    if (m_bIsReady)
        m_stream << i;
}

void CIPSocket::connectionReady()
{ m_bIsReady = true; }

void CIPSocket::connectionLost()
{ m_bIsReady = false; }

void CIPSocket::close()
{ QCoreApplication::exit(); }

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   CIPServer
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CIPServer::CIPServer(QObject* parent)
: QLocalServer(parent)
{
    if (!listen("DemoServer")) {
        throw ("Could not connect to 'DemoServer'");
    }
    connect(this, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(socketConnected()));
}

CIPServer::~CIPServer()
{}

void CIPServer::socketConnected()
{
    qDebug() << "Connected";
    m_pConnection = nextPendingConnection();
    m_stream.setDevice(m_pConnection);
    connect(m_pConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()), m_pConnection, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(m_pConnection, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(update()));
    connect(m_pConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(close()));
}

void CIPServer::update()
{
    if (m_pConnection->bytesAvailable() >= 4) {
        int i;
        m_stream >> i;
        qDebug() << i;
    }
}

void CIPServer::close()
{ QCoreApplication::exit(); }

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   CSender
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CSender::CSender(int iNumMessages)
: m_iNumMessages(iNumMessages)
{}

CSender::~CSender()
{}

void CSender::run()
{
    while (m_iNumMessages > 0) {
        emit sendMessage(m_iNumMessages);
        msleep(10);
        m_iNumMessages--;
    }
    emit allMessagesSent();
}
```

main.h:

```
#include <QtNetwork/QLocalServer>
#include <QtNetwork/QLocalSocket>
#include <QtCore/QDataStream>
#include <QtCore/QThread>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>


    /// \brief Creates a socket for inter-process communication
    class CIPSocket
        : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT;

    public:
        /// Constructor
        CIPSocket();
        /// Destructor
        virtual ~CIPSocket();

    public slots:
        /// Enables updating
        void connectionReady();
        /// Disables updating
        void connectionLost();
        /// Send the data
        void update(int i);
        /// Close the application
        void close();

    private:
        /// The target stream
        QDataStream m_stream;
        /// The socket connecting to server
        QLocalSocket* m_pSocket;
        /// Indicates if the socket is connected
        bool m_bIsReady;
    };

    /// \brief Creates a server for inter-process communication
    class CIPServer
        : public QLocalServer
    {
        Q_OBJECT;

    public:
        /// Constructor
        CIPServer(QObject* parent = NULL);
        /// Destructor
        virtual ~CIPServer();

    private slots:
        /// Connects the socket to the stream and to the update function
        void socketConnected();
        /// Reads the data from the stream and emits a the results
        void update();
        /// Close the application
        void close();

    private:
        /// The currently connected socket
        QLocalSocket* m_pConnection;
        /// The incoming stream
        QDataStream m_stream;
    };

    /// \brief Sends the messages via CIPSocket
    class CSender
        : public QThread
    {
        Q_OBJECT;

    public:
        /// Constructor
        CSender(int iNumMessages);
        /// Destructor
        virtual ~CSender();
        /// Sends the requestet number of messages in 10 ms steps
        virtual void run();

    signals:
        /// Sends the message via the CIPSocket
        void sendMessage(int);
        /// Informs about all messages being sent
        void allMessagesSent();

    private:
        /// The number of messages to send
        int m_iNumMessages;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The program works well as it is programmed: try the following:

start server - start client, sends data - server receives data - stop client - start client once more, sends data - server receives data ...

The program has no deadlock, and it does not freeze! The program is waiting for events in Qt eventloop in line 13:

```
app.exec();
```

The question is: what shall it do?

I assume, you like to quit the program after work, then insert:

```
void CIPServer::socketConnected()
{ . . .
  connect(m_pConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(theend()));
}
void CIPServer::theend()
{
    QCoreApplication::quit();
}
```

Try these actions:
start server - start client, sends data - server receives data - stop client – server stops also

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the answer does not address the described issue. My problem is not with the server not closing, but with CIPSocket hanging in the destructor, after sending 256+ messages. Hence the Socket is also not disconnecting. (I checked your approach nonetheless)